# How should I properly use Ember.js nested routing?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I have this route part, `/articles/`. I would like to create subroutes here, like `/` and `/list/`. This is how I am trying:

```
articles: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/admin/articles',
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
            "use strict";
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('toolbar', 'articlesToolbar');
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('main', 'articles');
        }
    }),
    list: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/list/',
        connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
            "use strict";
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('toolbar', 'articlesToolbar');
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('main', 'articles');
        }
    }),
    doLogout: function(router, context) {
        "use strict";
        router.transitionTo('login', context);
    }
}),
```

i must be doing something wrong, because it does not transition to the articles route. This is my routing log:

```
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'doSidebar' to state root.
STATEMANAGER: Entering null
STATEMANAGER: Entering root
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.articles
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'doSidebar' to state root.
STATEMANAGER: Entering null
STATEMANAGER: Entering root
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.media
```

But the `articles` url is not registered to the history -- if I click back, I get to the previous state, the one before `articles`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot route to non-leaf states, so you cannot transition to 'articles'.
Either add `initialState: 'index'` to your articles route or change your code to transition to `'articles.index'`

```
articles: Ember.Route.extend({
  route: '/admin/articles',
  initialState: 'index',
  index: Ember.Route.extend({
    //
```

Comment: InitialState it is. I knew about the leaf rule, but not about initialState. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You have no route defined for `/articles`. You need to change `route: '/admin/articles'` to `route: '/articles'` .